# Jackson ObjectMapper: specify required fields

Tags: java, json, object-object-mapping

When deserializing from json, is there an easy way for ObjectMapper to throw an exception when a required field is missing from json?

Comment: The `@JsonProperty` annotation does provide such a functionality. See: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required%28%29

Comment: After annotating a field with @JsonProperty(required=true), how can I detect it when this field is missing from json?

Comment: It should throw an exception while deserialization.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this work. Do you mind share some basic examples? Thanks.

Comment: It seems JsonProperty is not supported during deserialization. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/174